# oracledb in typeorm specify libdir path

Tags: typeorm, node-oracledb

I am trying to configure oracledb and typeorm for a project in nestjs, I can't find how I can pass libDir so that it takes the correct library, I already tested directly with javascript and node and if it can connect me to the database.

Greetings

Comment: I believe you found the answer to this? From Slack "I found the problem, it was because the windows PATH was pointing to another client that I have installed on the machine."

Comment: I found the problem, it was because the windows PATH was pointing to another client that I have installed on the machine.
If you have a similar error, check that the PATH in windows is correct (do not forget to restart), in linux it would be LD_LIBRARY_PATH